# XSL add fully qualified namespace to richtext

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I need to add namespace to all tags.

Input:

```
<div>
    <div>Content 1</div>        
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Data follows: </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
        <li>Line 3</li>
        <li>Line 4</li>
        <li>Line 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Output should be:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >Content 1</div>      
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >Content 2</div>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >Data follows: </div>
        <ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <li>Line 1</li>
            <li>Line 2</li>
            <li>Line 3</li>
            <li>Line 4</li>
            <li>Line 5</li>
        </ul>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >Content 3</div>
    </div>
```

Currently the XSL which I am using it is not adding the namespace in all the tags. For eg: it will add only to root div tag not the child div/ul or any other tags.

The XSL which I am using to transform:

```
<xsl:template match="I | u | em | strong | a | blockquote | div | ul | ol | li | span | sup | sub | br | table | tbody | tr | th | colgroup | col | td | img | hr | font">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks,
Gautam

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get your wanted output with XSLT and its normal serialization as it usually simply outputs namespace declarations where needed and if the parent `div` declares the XHTML namespace then that declaration is in scope for all descendant elements. Why do you need each element to have an explicit namespace declaration?

Comment: Because when there is no namespace in ul tag then XML is not getting validated. Its throwing error. So everytime we have to add either namespace or attribute type="disc".. then it goes fine.. even by adding separate div tag for ul works.

Comment: Well validation depends on the DTD or schema you use and perhaps on the validating parser. You might want to edit your question and describe exactly which parser, DTD or schema you use and which error message you get.